# unable to install packages on debian linux

Tags: debian, packages

I had been able to install packages in the past.  But when I try it as below now::

```
root@debian:/home/me# apt-get install git
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
root@debian:/home/me# uname -a
Linux debian 4.19.0-23-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.269-1 (2022-12-20) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

it is failing as seen above.

Trying 'dpkg --configure -a' yields::

```
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 2 expected programs not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
```

But, when I look for /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin, or /sbin, they do not exist.  Should I simply create those and problem solved?  If it is relevant, my Debian system, is a virtual machine, via VirtualBox.  All suggestions welcome.

Comment: in Debian, `/sbin` is usually a link to `/usr/sbin` ... and no, you can't just create those folders, they have contents that are essential (like the `ldconfig` and `start-stop-daemon` mentioned in the error) ... either restore from your most recent full backup, or, if you're like 99% of people and don't have one, backup any essential files and re-install Debian

Comment: Run:  

sudo apt-get --fix-missing update to get missing updates.

and

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade    ...    to install new dependencies   Try this an see if possibly it helps.

Comment: Thx for the fast responses.  I recalled that a while back I set things up so I could get updates for 'QGIS' and in doing so, I seemed to have caused an issue.  When I do "apt-get update" as root, I am getting: "W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://debian.qgis.org/debian buster InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY (and then some digits here).  I would like to undo this QGIS update portion, but cannot recall how.

Comment: Also, when I run "apt-get dist-upgrade" as root, I get -- "E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?"  Any ideas?

Comment: After several tests (thx for the tips John and Jaromanda X), I have opted for the Debian re-install approach, and all is well now.  Thx to both for good insights.